# Removing a single CSS element for one URL; Drupal 6

Tags: css, drupal-6

I have my Drupal theme set up with a notebook spine image in the middle, giving it a 50/50 page split.

The problem is, on a few pages, I want to get rid of that notebook spine and use the whole page. I have looked around on Drupal.org, but no luck.

Would this be an edit to the page.tpl or style.css?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2):

Add an id to your body tag on the page where you don't want the spine and add a second CSS rule for it like this:

The HTML:

```
<body id="nospine">
   <div id="page"><!-- your content here --></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#page {
   background:#fff url(spine.gif) top repeat-y; /* normally with spine */
}
#nospine #page {
   background:#fff; /* without the spine image */
}
```

All pages will now display the spine image unless you add the 'nospine' id to the body tag, easy!

Comment: Hey Matthew, Thanks! :) I am new to Drupal, and this is where I get lost. In a typical website, there would be a physical page in a directory. In Drupal it is all rendered through templates and themes, so in what file can I indicate the specific URL's that I want to exclude the CSS element from?